# Dynamic Foreign Key

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I've never faced on this structure before and maybe someone knows best way to do that.

I have two tables - tab1(client_id, tab2_id) and tab2 (id, client_id, client_date) - NNN hundreds mln rows, million new rows per day.

tab1.TAB2_ID is foreign key with tab2 (tab2.ID).

I am going to create a trigger in tab2 to keep updated the latest tab2.ID in the tab1 per client_id. It means that I will change foreign key which will force to recalc the index. What do you think, is it good idea?

Or better do not make a foreign key and just keep that ID, but I need to join tab1 and tab2 in reports to reach tab2.client_date.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What's the reason behind the requirement? Because this sounds like a terrible design! Are there really only those columns in the tables? If so, I would most likely combine the two tables into one.

Comment: There are so many possible ways to solve this sort of problem. Choosing the best approach demands a lot more specific information about your scenario, probably more information than would be appropriate for SO. What we can say is that a trigger is probably the worst solution, regardless of the specifics. On the scant information you've provided [Kevin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65146502/146325) is what I would have suggested.

Comment: We reviewed the requirements and this question is not anymore actual. Everything much easier. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this might not be your entire requirement, but aggregating data from one table into another is a good use of materialized views.

In the future please include actual DDL, DML to support a minimum reproducible example.

Let's start with `tab2`:

```
CREATE TABLE tab2 (
       id NUMBER,
       client_id NUMBER,
       client_date DATE);

ALTER TABLE tab2
ADD CONSTRAINT tab2_pk
PRIMARY KEY (id)
USING INDEX;
```

Create some fake data:

```
INSERT INTO tab2
SELECT LEVEL,
       MOD(LEVEL,
           5),
       trunc(SYSDATE) - MOD(LEVEL,
                            20)
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 100;

SELECT *
  FROM tab2;
```

Yields:

```
1   1   12/3/2020
2   2   12/2/2020
3   3   12/1/2020
4   4   11/30/2020
5   0   11/29/2020
6   1   11/28/2020
7   2   11/27/2020
8   3   11/26/2020
9   4   11/25/2020
10  0   11/24/2020
...
```

Now for the materialized view.  We want this view refreshed automatically when any data is changed in `tab2`.  For this we need to create a materialized view log to track changes on the fields we are interested in.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG 
ON tab2 WITH ROWID (id, client_id)
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

And then the materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tab1
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH fast
ON COMMIT
AS
SELECT client_id,
       MAX(id) AS tab2_id
  FROM tab2
 GROUP BY client_id;
```

Here is what `tab` looks like now:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tab1;

CLIENT_ID  TAB2_ID
2          97
4          99
0          95
3          98
1          96
```

So, here is the magic.  Let's insert a new row into `tab2`:

```
INSERT INTO tab2
VALUES
  (100,
   4,
   trunc(SYSDATE) + 100);
COMMIT;
```

And looking at `tab1` again we see:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tab1;

CLIENT_ID  TAB2_ID
2          97
4          100 <--- changed for new CLIENT_ID 4, ID 100
0          95
3          98
1          96
```

All of this being said I agree with Boneist: you really might want to reconsider if you need this aggregation, second table, if you are just going to join back to the original table anyways.

Comment: This may not be the correct solution (where correct means *what the Seeker actually needs to solve their real problem*) but just about anything is better than a trigger :)